# static member serialization

Tags: java, serialization

I read that 'Serialization Is Not for Static Elements' - but a simple example below tells me otherwise.

```
class superparent implements Serializable {
    int data = 0;

    public superparent(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getdata() {
        return data;
    }
}

public class statichost implements Serializable {
    int member = 0;
    public static superparent s = new superparent(20);

    public statichost(int data) {
        this.member = data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        statichost c = new statichost(6);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("testSer.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
            os.writeObject(c);
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("testSer.ser");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            c = (statichost) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("after: contained data is " + c.s.getdata());
    }
}
```

The output prints 20 when I would have expect 0 as per the statement above.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your test code cannot verify this situation. 
Because 20 is set by `public static superparent s=new superparent(20);` in class initialization, it is always set to 20 by JVM when classloading.

**If you want the initial data to be 0 and check the modification of the data to 20 can NOT be serialized**, then try

1. Use `public static superparent s=new superparent(0);` instead of 20 for initial value.
2. Comment out the readObject try-catch block for the first execution, and add the modification code **c.s.data=20** in the first try-catch block and write to file, then execute the code.
3. Comment out the writeObject try-catch block for the second execution, and execute the read Object
   code again. Then you can see the 20 can not be serialized into files, 0 is printed.

Comment: Congrats on the OP accepting your answer, which was an almost word for word copy of my own!

Comment: Looks like your one is more generic and better, but I have not read you answer when I post mine. Sorry for that...no one wants to copy other's answers that is stupid...

Answer (score 2):

It is because your `int data=0;` is not a static member of your class `superparent`.

Also I would like to point that class names should start with  a capital letter, if you have forgotten this recommendation

Comment: The question is about serializing the static "superparent" member, not the "data" member.

Answer (score 2):

Theres nothing extraordinary going on here. You have declared a static member variable for your class `statichost`. This variable is initialized when the class is loaded by the JVM, regardless of what triggers the loading of the class.

Serializing and deserializing a `statichost` instance has no bearing on the static fields, since they are associated with your class, not with your instance. If you want to test this, break out the serialization and deserialization into different blocks and perform these steps:

- Serialize your `statichost` instance
- Change the class so that `superparent` is initialized with 15, instead of 20
- Deserialize the `statichost` instance

If static fields are serialized, you would expect `c.s.getdata()` to report 20, but it will report 15.